# AJAX asynchronous requests not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I want to test asynchronous AJAX requests with jquery but it doesn't work as expected.

Here are my 3 requests :

```
idRpis.forEach(function(idRpi, index){
  console.log("Start"+index+" : "+Date.now());
  $.ajax({
    type      : 'POST',
    url       : AJAX,
    dataType  : 'json',
    async     : "true",
    data      : {
      action : "test"
    },
    success   : function(response) {
        console.log("End"+index+" : "+Date.now());
    }
  });
});
```

The PHP file called looks like that :

```
 //Pause for 3 seconds
 session_start();
 sleep(3);
```

The problem is that the 3 request are sent almost at the same time but arrive with a 3 seconds delay between each.

Is it not supposed to do the job in parallel and arrive at the same time ? That's what I would like to do.

Comment: There is no guarantee when they will return and run.

Comment: I'm sure a single ajax call can do the work. you don't necessary need 3 ajax call

Comment: Is there any more php code? If you are using sessions, each request will lock the session so the others will have to wait until it is finished.

Comment: No because in this example I would like to do the 3 "sleep" in parallel, not one by one. (the command "sleep" is just for the example)

Comment: @jeroen you were right, I was using sessions ! Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Thank's to @jeroen I found out that I was using "session_start()" and that locked the session so the requests had to wait until the previous has finished.